# moment duration error formatting with moment-duration-format

Tags: momentjs

I have a problem with the formatting using moment-duration-format. I'm passing the format **'y[y] M[m] w[w] d[d] h[hr] m[min]'** inside format.

But I'm getting hrs and mins instead of hr and min as the output.

eg : Im getting `1m 0w 3d 22hrs 30mins` as the output.

But what I need as output is `1m 0w 3d 22hr 30min`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the locale info to the format that you want. This might help you get started.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2?file=/src/index.js

```
var moment = require("moment");
require("moment-duration-format");
moment.updateLocale("sample", {
  durationLabelsStandard: {
    s: "singular second",
    ss: "first plural seconds",
    sss: "next plural seconds"
  },
  durationLabelsShort: {
    s: "singular sec",
    ss: "first plural secs",
    sss: "next plural secs"
  }
});
console.log(
  moment
    .duration(76800006, "seconds")
    .format("y[y] M[m] w[w] d[d] h[hr] m[min]", {
      locale: "sample"
    })
);
```